# Calculate sphere volume in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I calculate sphere volume in Prolog?

I have such code:

```
area(R,P):-P is 3.14 * R *R.
vol(R,P,V):-V is 4/3 * R * area(R,P).
```

I'm getting such an error trying to compile the above code:

```
fatal error: unknown operation in arithmetic expression (area/2)
compilation failed
```

What's wrong in this code, does it mean that I can't use one predicate inside another? I'm using `gprolog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because gnu-prolog does not allow to add new arithmetic functions (unless you recompile its 'kernel').

Anyways, you can compute the volume by first computing the area and then using that area to compute the volume. i.e. :

```
area(R,P):-P is 4.0 * 3.14 * R *R.

vol(R,V):-
  area(R,P),
  V is 1/3 * R * P.
```

Comment: Prolog code is ok, but the [area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere) should be `4 * pi * R * R`

Comment: @CapelliC: Thanks, fixed answer to reflect proper area formula.